# Checking result count

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project that requires getting posts from my database. I am trying to get the posts that are posted by the user and other users unless they are private.

My SQL query is

```
SELECT . . .,COUNT(F.user_id) AS is_following FROM posts AS P INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.id = P.user_id LEFT JOIN followers AS F ON F.user_id = :userid AND F.following_id = U.id WHERE *If matches search* AND U.private = 0 OR U.id = :userid OR is_following = 1 ORDER BY. . .
```

I am selecting where the user is following the posters and counting it if 0 it means they are not following and 1 would mean 1 result, therefore, following them. Also I am checking if private is 0 meaning the account is public.

The problem is while I have the `is_following = 1` it returns no results if I remove it though it does return results but not all.

**Tables:**

```
users: id|username|private|...
followers: userid|followingid
posts: id|userid|body
```

**Content:**

users:

```
user1|test1|1 (This is the user running the request)
user2|test2|1
user3|test3|1
```

followers:

```
user1|user2 (User searching follows test2)
```

posts:

```
post1|user1|HelloWorld
post2|user2|Hello_World
post3|user3|Hello-World
```

The expected outcome is to return post1 and post2 but not post3 since user3 is private (private is set to true/1) and user1 does no follow test3, but it should display user2's post since user1 follows user2

Comment: Could you give some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih The expected result is to include posts from where `is_following = 1`

Comment: you can use `HAVING COUNT(F.user_id) = 1` on your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct.

There are two kinds of groups

1. private is *0* meaning the account is public
2. private is *1* need to find the following User on followers table.

A simple way you can make two query one is for  private is *0* , another is for   private is *1* ,then use `UNION ALL` combine those.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT p.*
  FROM users as u 
  INNER JOIN posts AS P ON p.userid = u.id  
  WHERE u.private = 0 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT p.*
  FROM users as u 
  INNER JOIN posts AS P ON p.userid = u.id  
  RIGHT JOIN followers AS F ON F.followingid = u.id
  WHERE u.private = 1 AND f.userid = :userid 
)t
```

Or use `exists` to check it

```
SELECT p.*
FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN posts AS P ON p.userid = u.id  
WHERE u.private = 0 OR exists 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM followers AS F LEFT JOIN users ON F.followingid = users.id
    WHERE u.id = users.id 
    and users.private 
    and f.userid = :userid 
)
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50ef05/1*

**EDIT**

if you want to get the user is or isn't `is_following`,you could follow like this.

then you could find which user have been `is_following` on outer `where` clause .

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT p.*,0 as 'is_following'
  FROM users as u 
  INNER JOIN posts AS P ON p.userid = u.id  
  WHERE u.private = 0 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT p.*,1 
  FROM users as u 
  INNER JOIN posts AS P ON p.userid = u.id  
  RIGHT JOIN followers AS F ON F.followingid = u.id
  WHERE u.private = 1 AND f.userid = 'user1'
)t
/*where is_following = 1*/
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7f6c/10*

Comment: I just tried that and it is only displaying posts if they follow the user. I want it if the user is public I want to display the post but if they are private I only want to display that post if  F result is 1

Comment: It should only matter if the user is following the poster if the poster is private, if the poster is public it should be displayed and ignore the following status

Comment: Is there any simplier way to add the COUNT check to the end of my current query?

Comment: Which count did you want to get following user amount  or totle user amout on the query?

Comment: For each post's poster, lets say its on post2 it will check if user2 is private and if they are check if user1 is following them with count is count = 0 means not following, 1 would mean they follow the private poster

Answer (score 1):

The reason it returns no results when you have the `is_following` condition is that you are trying to use an alias in a WHERE clause which is not permitted by MySQL. Replace `is_following` with `COUNT(F.user_id)` and it should work.

Comment: Having `COUNT(F.user_id) = 1` made it still return null

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output to help debug?